# Simple Python SMTP Enumeration script

Tags: python, smtp-auth

I am trying to write a simple Python SMTP enumeration script, which reads usernames from a text file (filename supplied as the second argument - `sys.argv[2]`), and checks them against an SMTP server (hostname or ip supplied as the first argument - `sys.argv[1]`. I found something that is kind of close, and tweaked it a bit, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import sys

users = sys.argv[2]
for line in users:
    line = line.strip()
    if line!='':
        users.append(line)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((sys.argv[1], 25))
fn = s.makefile('rwb')

fn.readline()                
fn.write('HELO testing.com \r\n')
fn.flush()
fn.readline()

for user in users:
    fn.write('VRFY %s\r\n' % user)
    fn.flush()
    print '%s: %s' % (user, fn.readline().strip())

fn.write('QUIT\r\n')
fn.flush()
s.close()
```

However, when I run the script (for example):

```
./smtp-vrfy.py 192.168.1.9 users.txt
```

It results in an error:

**File "./smtp-vrfy.py", line 10, in 
    users.append(line)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'**

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it? Perhaps there is an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`users` is a file name, but you're not reading it. Instead, see what happens:

```
>>> users = "users.txt"
>>> for line in users:
...     print(line)
...
u
s
e
r
s
.
t
x
t
```

You probably want:

```
with open(users) as f:
    for line in f:
        # ...
```

Even better:

```
filename = sys.argv[2]
with open(filename) as f:
    users = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if line]
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I'm a bit confused - you mean replace my first lines of code with something like this:                                                       `with open(users) as f:
    for line in f:
        username = line.replace('\n', '')
        s.send('VRFY ' + 'username' + '\r\n')
        print 'Testing with user: %s' % username`

Comment: @Cain That would be ok too :)

Comment: I feel like I'm almost there, but not quite. I used your suggestion (your last bit of code) above, but it is generating an error **File "./smtp-vrfy.py", line 21, in <module>
    user = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines if line]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable**

Comment: You're correct, I added the parentheses, and now the script doesn't spit out any more tracebacks, but it looks like it's trying to check the whole list at once in a *pythonic* format, because this is the output I get -->> **Testing with user: ['root', 'backup', 'bob', 'rick', 'david', 'harry', 'apache', 'igor', 'ron', 'mike', 'larry', 'joseph']
550 5.1.1 user... User unknown**....Is it because the text file has the usernames in a column, instead of a comma-separated list? I've been at this all day, but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: @Cain No. Actually, that should be `users` (note the last s). Like this: `users = [line.strip() for line...` and so on. Then you'll check each element in your loop `for user in users`...

Comment: You were right, I finally did it! It works as expected! :) I'm going to accept your answer. Thanks for hanging in there with me.